# Java check style : Final Parameter reference variable assignment

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am working on resolving Checkstyle warnings in a Java project.

Suppose this is the method i have:

```
public SomeObject someObjectBehavior(SomeObject oldSomeObject,
    SomeObject newSomeObject) {

    if(oldSomeObject == null) { 
        oldSomeObject = newSomeObject; 
    } 
}
```

When I enable the Checkstyle, it notifies

> Parameter oldSomeObject should be final
>
> Parameter newSomeObject should be final

When I convert both the parameters like this:

```
public SomeObject someObjectBehavior(final SomeObject oldSomeObject,
    final SomeObject newSomeObject) {

    if(oldSomeObject == null) {
        oldSomeObject = newSomeObject;  //Assignment operation
    } 
}
```

So, now assignment operation is not possible, there is a error in Java code

> The final local variable oldSomeObject cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment.

If any one of you have faced this, so please help, as I am trying to resolve all the Checkstyle issues.

Thank You

Regards

Ankur Sharma

Comment: In Java, method arguments are treated like local variables, so assigning a value to a method argument has no effect on the caller of the method. It only confuses readers of your method, who might think that `oldSomeObject` refers to a value that was passed in, but instead contains a value that was assigned to it in the method.

Comment: @AnkurSharma  What is your use-case for assigning object values passed by parameter?

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky, actually that was a pre written code, and we were given the code to resolve only checkstyle issues as many as possible. I'd have modified the code for above mentioned assignment, but we were not allowed to modify the code at that time...so this situation came up.

Answer (score 6):

It is considered bad style to reassign parameters. You are supposed to create a new local variable.

Comment: Well, i am not writing a fresh code, It's an existing code, so i have to resolve all the checkstyle issues.

Comment: and another thing, oldSomeObject is just a reference variable here, so i am just assigning reference, is there any way?

Comment: @AnkurSharma the code is it working? don't change it.. open for extension close to modification.

Comment: @nachokk, yes it is a working code, without check style, i am able to make builds n all. What do you mean by open for extension brother?

Comment: @AnkurSharma  ~"i have to resolve all the checkstyle issues".  Why?

Answer (score 4):

The example method you provide

```
public SomeObject someObjectBehavior(final SomeObject oldSomeObject,final SomeObject newSomeObject) { 
    if(oldSomeObject == null) { 
        oldSomeObject = newSomeObject;  //Assignment operation
    } 
}
```

is a perfect example of why making your parameters `final` is a Good Idea. Without making your variables `final`, you might not realize that your method does nothing, since reassigning a parameter reference doesn't change anything outside of your method.

Comment: Well, I got the point, that final is a good thing, which check style imposes, but what if my oldSomeObject is null, and i have to assign the newSomeObject reference to oldSomeObject,  They are just the reference variable, so when method completes, and control goes back to the called place, now oldSomeObject and newSomeObject both are pointing to same memory location(when oldSomeObject was null), so i want to know, how should obey the checkstyle and also doesn't break the java rules :)

Comment: @Ankur: It doesn't matter what you do to the `oldSomeObject` reference inside the method, any changes will be discarded once the method ends, since it is a local variable.

Comment: issue is that, java gives me error message, that assignment can't be done, as the param(oldSomeOBject) is final(which is obvious)..but my thinking is that, there must be some way, when check style notification shouldn't come and also i do not see any error in code as well. :|

Comment: actually, we are using Jenkins for the build, so we have to resolve all the check style issues (most of the), but this is some uneven situation came in between,

Comment: @Ankur: Since the assignment accomplishes nothing, the best way to fix the error is to simply remove it.

Comment: thats an option, if oldSomeObject is null, so do all the stuff in the method and return newSomeObject(as you need the mem loc of newSomeObject now), and don't go for assignment operation, thats the passive way i have, but ypu're right as well to some extent,,,I'll take it as final solution, if i'll get nothing from this post, Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

The main reason for defining the parameters as final is to avoid unintentionally overwriting them later. If you define them final you can always be sure that the parameter is always what was given into the method in the first place.

It is better style to use a new local variable if you want to change the value. In many cases assigning variables only once makes the code much more readable. It's not always possible but often it is.

Try something like

```
Object realObject;
if (oldSomeObject != null) { 
  realObject = oldSomeObject;
} else {
  realObject = newSomeObject;
}
```

Comment: That i understand, but thing is that, i need to pass the refernce of newSomeObject to oldSomeObject in case when oldSomeObject is null, and when both params are final.

Comment: realObject has the reference now, thats fine, how do i assign this back to my calling place?

Comment: you return it and assign the result of the method call to your variable.

Answer (score -3):

This checkstyle rule is a perfect example of shoot first (gotta be final else it's wrong) and ask questions later (does re-assignment actually takes place).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. If you answer the question, you will most likely get enough rep to add comments :-)